# How to generate variables from stucture field names in matlab?

Tags: matlab, matrix, struct

Let say I have a structure data in workspace as follows

```
data.a={'1','2'};
data.b=[1,2,3];
data.c='hello';
```

I need to have following variables in workspace:

```
a={'1','2'};
b=[1,2,3];
c='hello';
```

Please advise me how to move forward with this?

Why I need to do this(in case there is better alternative to achieve my requirement):

I have around 140 .mat files. Now, I need to replace a string in all of these .mat files. This string can be part of a string array, cell array or a stand alone variable. I run a loop for all these mat files and load them as follows:

```
tempLoad=load('filename.mat');
```

Then I extract fields of the structure `tempLoad`, which gives me all the variables inside `'filename.mat'`. Then I can work through all the variables and replace the error string. Now, I need to save back the `'filename.mat'` in the **exact format**.

I cannot use `save('filename.mat','tempLoad')` or simply `save('filename.mat')` because original storage of variables is not maintained by them.

So I need to convert all the fields of `tempLoad` to variables, then clear `tempLoad` and call `save` function after that.

Comment: Not the answer, but maybe you should read [**this**](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/import_export/load-parts-of-variables-from-mat-files.html) to optimize your general approach.

Comment: I'll just put it there since you had what you want, but to do what you original asked you could use [`assignin`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/assignin.html)

Comment: Good question. +1 for including the reason behind your requirements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You **can** save the struct `tempLoad` to `'filename.mat'` without changing the structure of the mat file using the `'-struct'` format:

```
save( 'filename.mat', '-struct', 'tempLoad' );
```

See [doc `save`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/save.html) for more information.

You might also consider using [`matfile`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matfile.html) objects to access the saved matfiles and update the specific string directly without loading/saving the entire file each time.

Answer (score 1):

for saving have you tried using the -struct arg:

```
matData = load ( 'filename.mat' );

save ( 'filename2.mat', '-struct', 'matData' )
```

That should allow you to save the original struct back to file.  From what you said I am assuming that this is the real problem...

Answer (score 0):

I think the other answers may help your problem. If you still really want to save new variables from the fields, then you could use

```
f = fieldnames(data);

for ii = 1:numel(f)
    eval([f{ii} ' = data.' f{ii}]);
end
```

Note that if you are using this, [**there is probably a better way**](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/string-evaluation.html) to think about the problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: `eval` is evil: see [why not using `eval`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/string-evaluation.html).

Comment: It's not recommended, and I did say that in the answer (and a disclaimer at the end)

Comment: I took the liberty of editing your answer to explicitly link to mathworks webpage on why not to use `eval`. hope it's okay with you.

Comment: Thanks very much, my disclaimer was a little half-hearted